# how to merge tables using mysql database?

Tags: mysql, merge

I have two tables suppose table 1 has two columns with short names and full names of USA and another table has only short name.
I want to write a MySQL query to update all short names of table 2 with a full name in table 1 on matching with short same of table 1

```
Table 1                   Table 2        after query I want Table 2

C1   C2                    C6                       C6

NY    New York             NY                       New York

NJ    New Jersey           NJ                       New Jersey
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Table 2 has a STATE field wide enough to support the full state name and that you want to overwrite the short state name with the long state name. On MySQL 5.0 I believe the UPDATE JOIN statement should be written more like this:

```
UPDATE Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 on Table2.state=Table1.state 
SET Table2.state=Table1.Full_name
```

I think this link has the clearest answer 
http://blog.ookamikun.com/2008/03/mysql-update-with-join.html